# Git contribution analysis tool

Tags: time-management, git

I'm looking for a Git Repository analysis tool. I would like to check my (and also my team) commit activity.

I'm looking for a tool that can help people to do accurate timesheet, crosscheck and validate them. I also want to check the activity of a project to evaluate the time spent on it.

I know this king of tool may be inaccurate for some people. My objective is not to blame or to check on specific person. I'm also de developer. I know I can use it for me because I do many small commits so I can clearly see the days I work on this or that repository.

My repositories are on Bitbucket.

Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829302/4341322) locked [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42715893/4341322) over in SO about the same topic that have attracted lots of suggestion, and I also found a few newer tools:

- [RepoSense](https://reposense.org/ug/index.html#generating-a-report) (focus: chronological visualisation of contributions to a team's multiple, related repositories)
- [codescene.io](https://codescene.io/) (focus: technical debt & team organisation; ideas from [Your Code as a Crime Scene](https://pragprog.com/titles/atcrime/your-code-as-a-crime-scene/))

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the git log function to get a comma separated list of the commits over a given period and then use a spreadsheet or tools such as [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to process it.

`git log --since='2019/01/01' --date=short --pretty=format:'%an,%ad,%s --all > commits.csv`

Will give a `commits.csv` file with a line for each commit containing Author Name, Author Date, Subject - this will give you the number of commits each day per author ***but*** not the impact of each commit however this is not easy to measure.